# Highlight filtered element in row angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a table that filteres out operator and asset using simple inline ng-repeat angular filter.
However in some rows there are more than one operator (ie., second row) which I'm displaying inside scroll.When filtered by operator the rows are getting filtered but not able to display in the row(have to scroll to see the filtered result) the exact operator that is selected .

Example: When selected operator `Jill` ,I want to see Jill as its inside the row hidden under scroll.

[**Plunker link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DDe9HT?p=preview)

HTML Snippet:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:truckName| filter:operatorName">
                  <td>
                    <div ng-class="{'set-height':item.assetOperator.length>'1'}" ng-if="item.assetOperator.length>0">
                     <span ng-repeat="operator in item.assetOperator">
                     {{operator.name}},
                     </span>
                     </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>{{item.assetName}}</td>
               </tr>
```

Comment: see this https://plnkr.co/edit/9y4VqD4KIazg8oTn0Jef?p=preview

Comment: @Hadi Thanks.Is it not possible to hide other elements that dosen't match the model?

Comment: see updated sample https://plnkr.co/edit/9y4VqD4KIazg8oTn0Jef?p=preview

Comment: Working!!!Can you please answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `filter` service for this.write filter as following :
I doesn't write this filter.

and for hide other elements use `filter` in second `ng-repeat` loop.

```
app.filter('highlight', function() {
return function(text, selectedWord) {
  if(selectedWord) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(selectedWord, "g");
    return text.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlighted">' + selectedWord + '</span>');
  }
  else {
    return text;
   }
 };
});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9y4VqD4KIazg8oTn0Jef?p=preview)